# document.getElementById("<%= errorIcon.ClientID %>"); is giving null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to have server + client-side validation for my registration page. I want to invoke a JS func when my TextBox control loses focus(onBlur).

**Code in aspx page**

```
<div id="nameDiv">              
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelName" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelName" runat="server" Text="Enter Your Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxName" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Your Name" 
              onBlur="check(this)"></asp:TextBox>
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle errorSign" id="errorIcon" runat="server"></i>                      
            <asp:Label ID="labelNameError" runat="server" Text="Name can't be blank" ForeColor="Red"> 
              </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function check(txtBox) {
    var errIcon = document.getElementById("<%= errorIcon.ClientID %>");
    txt = txtBox.value;
    if (txt.length < 1)
        errIcon.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.errorSign{
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:30px;
    left:1050px;
    top:220px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans do you know how .NET works?

Comment: Why are you using  runat="server" on an <i> element? just drop it and use the regular id.

Comment: You are not actually using it. How about `this.closest("#nameDiv").querySelector(".errorSign")`

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle errorSign" ID="errorIcon" runat="server"></i>` Let asp.net set the id than you can use ClientId

Comment: @Eldar um, how is that any different than OP has?

Comment: Are you sure `check(this)` works? I have not worked .NET and JS together but `this` works differently in JS

Comment: `this` would be the textbox, that is how JavaScript works @alireza

Comment: @epascarello **"ID"** is server side id.

Comment: be easier to do it without ids. `var errIcon = txtBox.nextElementSibling`

Comment: Where is your javascript hosted?  Is it in an external `.js` file?  If so, it's never going to work

Comment: Little mistake corrected, instead of txt.style.visibility = "visible"; it is errIcon.style.visibility="visible" Still same problem

Comment: @Eldar I think youre missing the point here, epascarello is correct, you dont even need the id to achieve the functionality needed. You also dont need the 'i' element rendered on the server.

Comment: @Vince guys I tried without runat="server" but still, it can't find the element and gives null. And this keyword thing works absolutely well and I even tried to find the textBox Element using every possible method but again the same problem persists.

Comment: document.getElementById("errorIcon");

Comment: @freefaller yes its an external js file, can you please elaborate the functionality of why is it not working?

Comment: I was trying to tell how server side rendering works. Wasn't focusing anything else. By the way its not next sibling its previous sibling. you can use also `var errorIcon = txtBox.closest('.errorSign')`

Comment: Because external .js files are not processed via ASP.Net (IIS will just send the file without any changes).  In order for the code to work the `<%=...%>` must be within the `.aspx/.ascx` file

Comment: `<%= errorIcon.ClientID %>` is a server-side expression. You would need to render the javascript on the server before sending it to the browser for that to work. If that is literally the javascript you see in the browser dev tools or page source then it won't work because that is not javascript, it is just a string at that point.

Comment: @epascarello thanks man, nextElementSibling worked for me. But still, it tingles me why is it not able to find that element by id, maybe I am missing something in the functionality or life cycle of aspx web page of how it renders the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has stated via a comment that...

> yes its an external js file

The reason why it's failing is that `.js` files are not processed by ASP.Net and will be sent to the browser without any changes.  That means the browser is receiving the line exactly as it's written...

```
var errIcon = document.getElementById("<%= errorIcon.ClientID %>");
```

---

There are multiple ways to fix this... the first is probably not ideal, but it is to put the script into your `.aspx` or `.ascx` file.

That would mean that the script (being part of an ASP.Net processed page) will have the actual `id` of the control, instead of the `<%=..%>`.

---

The second, and probably better, way is to use the `class` name directly, rather than the `id`...

```
var errIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("errorSign")[0];
```

As `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements (because it's possible for multiple elements on the page to have the same class) the above will return the first item in that array.  If your code is more complicated, you'll need to amend it accordingly

---

Another option (thanks to [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)) is to use `nextElementSibling`, but that is likely to break if you change the HTML for some reason (say a redesign of the page)...

```
var errIcon = txtBox.nextElementSibling;
```